# Are these sentences grammar corrected? (お貸し、お借り)

Tags: grammar, sentence

> A: この本をお借りしたいんですが。
>   B: すみません この本はお貸しできません。

I got a little confused when it comes to these word like お借り、お貸し。

Comment: Hi, thanks for your first question on Japanese Language Stack Exchange! As a new member, please do familiarise yourself with the rules and guidance over what sort of questions you can ask and how to ask them (e.g. http://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic http://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). In general, you should demonstrate your own research efforts. That way, others will better understand your issue, and in turn can give you an answer that works best for you. It's also of course nice to put effort into your questions, if you expect others to do the same in their answers

Comment: In this particular case, can you explain you got confused by those words?

Comment: @ajsmart At a guess the questioner is not familiar with the お借りする form of the verb. Is there not an existing answer to this question, a duplicate? I looked for one but didn't find this question.

Comment: I am the questioner. Actually I'm learning japanese by myself and don't have someone who can correct the grammar. I don't sure if the sentences I wrote above are grammatically corrected. That's what I wanted to know. And sorry for being late.

Answer (score 1):

お貸しする is a "humble" way of saying 貸す and similar for お借りする, a "humble" form of 借りる.

There is lots of information on the web about these, for example here on this site:

[Usage of お+[verb stem]+する for humble form and お+[verb stem]+になる for honorific form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2590/usage-of-%E3%81%8Averb-stem%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-for-humble-form-and-%E3%81%8Averb-stem%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B-for-honorific-fo)

Comment: Thank you so much! :)