# Why does 「借りる」 become 「借りします」 in the title 「彼女、お借りします」?

Tags: ichidan-verbs, inflection

I recently noticed the title for the anime 「[彼女]{かのじょ}、お[借]{か}りします」 uses the verb 「借りる」.
It is well known that it is a ichidan verb and the expect inflection is 「借ります」, but in the anime title it is seen as 「借りします」.

What function does the extra 「し」 provide and more importantly, why is added?

Comment: Look up kenjougo.

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2590/1628

Answer (score 5, accepted):

お借りします is actually a combination of 借りる and する. お借りします is a humble form of 借ります. It is created by adding お to the verb stem (借り) and then adding that to します.

So, you would use the humble form anytime you are refering to your own actions when they are related to someone you are showing respect to.